# Set available orientation to toolbar in ArcMap using ArcObjects

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, toolbar

We are creating a very huge extension for ArcMap and in the process, we have created a lot of new custom toolbars. These toolbars contains both buttons and custom controls. These custom controls can only be viewed in a horizontal orientation (they are drop-downs for the most part).

I was wondering if there is a flag I can set on my objects in one of the interface to tell ArcMap that these toolbar are only available for horizontal orientation (this mean that when the user is trying to place them on the screen, using the docking mechanism, ArcMap doesn't offer the docking in vertical orientation for example).

I'm using the `IToolBarDef` and have been searching the documentation for another interface but all I can find is an Orientation properties for the ToolbarControl which I can't use because I work with ArcObjects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is unfortunately no API exposed in ArcObjects to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Even if it's not the answer I wanted, I think you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have some control over the positioning of the toolbar via the `Dock()` method on [ICommandBar](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ICommandBar.htm). To say a tool bar can never be docked vertically is not possible. If you play around with the ESRI toolbars such as Effects or 3D Analyst which have drop down controls not even the ESRI toolbars can deal with docking vertically.